# Selection of tableview cell's index path

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I have a question regarding the selection of table cells.

I have three grouped tables which are used as forms, only one of which should be in view at a time. So in the nav controller I have a button which presents another table in a popover with the title of all three forms and will control which form is currently available. So to show only one at a time manually is easy enough, but how do I go about detecting the selection of a certain cells indexPath upon selection and communicate that selection with another view controller?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it as part of

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

for the table view delegate.

Also, it might be worth considering using a segmented control for the selection.